# Make a WPF Scroll Viewer scroll regardless of mouse position

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that has a tool bar then a content control that nests a grid that contains a Tabcontrol and a ScrollViewer that wraps a TabPanel.

The scrollviewer works great, but only if my mouse is hovering over the tab control. How can I get the scroll viewer to scroll as long as my cursor is in the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to capture the event in the Window and raise it in the TabControl, something around this (untested):

```
private void Window_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Handled)
    {       
        e.Handled = true;
        var eventArg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
        eventArg.RoutedEvent = MouseWheelEvent;
        eventArg.Source = sender;
        MyTabControl.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
    }
}
```